# Angular validation for fields to be valid but not required

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation

I have the following in my template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="work_phone">Work Phone</label>
    <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        name="workPhone"
        ng-class="{'borderRed': contactInformation.workPhone.$invalid  && contactInformation.submitted}"
        ng-model="controller.contactInformation.workPhone"
        ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"
        maxlength="10"
        id="work_phone">

    <small class="error"
        ng-show="contactInformation.workPhone.$invalid && !contactInformation.workPhone.$pristine && contactInformation.submitted">
            That's not a valid phone number (only numerics are allowed)!
    </small>
</div>
```

Conditions:
**1.** If the field is blank/untouched, the form should stay valid.
**2.** If there is any value in the field then it should be validated against the regex provided in `ng-pattern`.

Looks very trivial. I know. But for some stupid reason, unable to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand your problem you want allow only numerics you can use this directive to block every other caracters :

```
    .directive('onlyDigits', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        function inputValue(val) {
            if (val) {
                var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                if (digits !== val) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
                return parseInt(digits,10);
            }
            return undefined;
        }            
        ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
    }
};
```

});

And add the directive to your input, it's faster and you haven't to use ng-pattern :

```
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           name="workPhone"
                           maxlength="10"
                           id="work_phone" onlyDigits>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form currently stays valid to begin, because you're checking for `$pristine`.  Try using `$setPristine()` when the form is empty to reset it, so no longer gets the `error` class.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your regex so that it allows empty strings:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*$/"
```

Comment: so is it that if ng-pattern is defined for an input, it WILL be checked for validity even if 'required' part is skipped?